# Early stopping in Bert Trainer instances

Tags: python, deep-learning, neural-network, huggingface-transformers, huggingface

I am fine-tuning a BERT model for a multiclass classification task. My problem is that I don't know how to add "early stopping" to those Trainer instances. Any ideas?

Answer (score 63, accepted):

There are a couple of modifications you need to perform, prior to correctly using the `EarlyStoppingCallback()`.

```
from transformers import EarlyStoppingCallback, IntervalStrategy
...
...
# Defining the TrainingArguments() arguments
args = TrainingArguments(
   f"training_with_callbacks",
   evaluation_strategy = IntervalStrategy.STEPS, # "steps"
   eval_steps = 50, # Evaluation and Save happens every 50 steps
   save_total_limit = 5, # Only last 5 models are saved. Older ones are deleted.
   learning_rate=2e-5,
   per_device_train_batch_size=batch_size,
   per_device_eval_batch_size=batch_size,
   num_train_epochs=5,
   weight_decay=0.01,
   push_to_hub=False,
   metric_for_best_model = 'f1',
   load_best_model_at_end=True)
```

You need to:

1. Use `load_best_model_at_end = True` (`EarlyStoppingCallback()` requires this to be `True`).
2. `evaluation_strategy` = `'steps'` or `IntervalStrategy.STEPS` instead of `'epoch'`.
3. `eval_steps = 50` (evaluate the metrics after `N steps`).
4. `metric_for_best_model = 'f1'`

In your `Trainer()`:

```
trainer = Trainer(
    model,
    args,
    ...
    compute_metrics=compute_metrics,
    callbacks = [EarlyStoppingCallback(early_stopping_patience=3)]
)
```

Of course, when you use `compute_metrics()`, for example it can be a function like:

```
def compute_metrics(p):    
    pred, labels = p
    pred = np.argmax(pred, axis=1)
    accuracy = accuracy_score(y_true=labels, y_pred=pred)
    recall = recall_score(y_true=labels, y_pred=pred)
    precision = precision_score(y_true=labels, y_pred=pred)
    f1 = f1_score(y_true=labels, y_pred=pred)    
return {"accuracy": accuracy, "precision": precision, "recall": recall, "f1": f1}
```

The return of the `compute_metrics()` should be a dictionary and you can access whatever metric you want/compute inside the function and return.

Note: In newer `transformers` version, the usage of `Enum` `IntervalStrategy.steps` is recommended (see `TrainingArguments()`) instead of plain `steps` string, the latter being soon subject to deprecation.

Comment: apart from `f1`, other metric like `bleu` can also be used along with early stopping.

Comment: Yes, definitely, depending on the task at hand

Comment: Why do I need the evaluation strategy to be `steps`? Why can't it be `epoch`?

Comment: Can't say much about that, it's the way the framework is developed @omermazig

Comment: But you can easily simulate the epoch, since batch_size * number_steps == epoch length. (800 samples, you have BS == 8 and 100 steps).

Comment: it looks like load_best_model_at_end=True doesn't work correctly when 8 bit quantization is used. Do you know any solution for this?

Comment: No, I haven't tried that, you can open an issue on their repo once you determined that this is the problem.